# htaccess redirect double slash URL 443

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, slash

I have a webpage that's reachable via HTTPS and I have some Urls with a double-slash (//) included. Those I want to replace with single-slash (/) or just rewrite/redirect to another page.

```
https://www.domain.com/us//whatever/page/
https://www.domain.com/us/whatever/page/
```

Normally I do redirects like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^us/xyz/?$ https://www.domain.com/us/newpage/? [NC,L,R=301]
```

And double-slashes (//) in the RewriteRule don't work for for the htaccess redirects :/

---

I've already searched for a solution for replacing // with / and I found:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

But when I use this snippet and I open the URL with the double-slash - this happens:

Opened url: `https://www.domain.com/us//whatever/page/`

Redirects to: `http://www.domain.com:443/us/whatever/page/`

Need help here. How can I fix this?

And is there an additional way to rewrite just a **specific url** that includes a double-slash (//)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Look like there is something else interfering, can you show the full current `.htaccess`

Comment: Can't provide the complete .htaccess because it is not my private project. But yes, there is lots of other stuff in there.

I've fixed it by using this:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$ [NC]`

`RewriteRule . https://www.domain.com%1/%2 [L,R=301]`

I just don't know if this is the "right" way to do it. But it works.